# Convert timestamp Jan 05 11:45 to DD/MM/YY HH:MM format in Unix korn shell

Tags: date, unix, solaris, ksh

My program goes as shown below where $i is a file.

```
TIMESTAMP=`ls -ltr $i | awk '{print $6,$7,$8;}'`
```

Output of this is `Jan  6 12:13`.

For sorting based on the date, I need to convert it to the format `DD/MM/YY HH:MM`.

Also please suggest if there is a way of sorting the files with the timestamp in the format Jan  6 12:13.

I am currently using Korn shell. Solaris 5.10.

Comment: When you are using th `-t` option with `ls`, it should already be sorting the files based on modification time. Why do need to sort it again?

Comment: It's a lot easier to sort timestamps in the standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. With "DD/MM/YY HH:MM", Feb 10 will precede Jan 11.

Answer (score 2):

**Under absolutely *no* circumstances, parse ls(1) output!**

Instead, **use the right tool for the job**. If you need to sort ls output, use ls’ various sort options. If you need to do other processing, make use of a tool… in the Solaris 8 installation I have access to, GNU stat is installed, which makes this easy:

```
tg@stinky:~ $ stat -c '%y %n' /bin/[ck]sh
2008-07-08 14:16:07.000000000 +0200 /bin/csh
2008-06-10 16:28:32.000000000 +0200 /bin/ksh
tg@stinky:~ $ uname -a
SunOS stinky 5.8 Generic_117350-61 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240 Solaris
```

Otherwise, you could use scripting languages with stat(2) access, such as Perl, to display times for pathnames, like this (be aware of newlines in filenames, though):

```
tg@stinky:~ $ find /bin/[ck]sh | perl -MPOSIX -ne 'chomp; print POSIX::strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M\n",localtime((stat)[9]));'
08/07/2008 14:16
10/06/2008 16:28
```

But, as others already pointed out in comments, `%Y-%m-%d` is indeed easier to sort.

The Korn Shell does not have any built-in functions for time manipulation.

The “magic chars in filenames”-safe version of this (also tested under Solaris 8) is:

```
find /bin/[ck]sh -print0 | perl -0 -MPOSIX -ne 'chomp; print POSIX::strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M\n",localtime((stat)[9]));'
```

Of course, the `find /bin/[ck]sh` part is just an example, you can feed any pathname list you have to the command.

Comment: Which `find` command are you using for `find /bin/[ck]sh -print0` on Solaris 8?

Comment: @AndrewHenle apparently `/sw/bin/find`… I just have a shell account on that system. But if the OP doesn’t have a `find` with `-print0` they better not have any funny chars in their filenames ☺